# Circles Chords and parallel lines

Tags: circles

I was going thru this question - Two Chords Ab, Cd of Lengths 5 Cm, 11 Cm Respectively of a Circle Are Parallel. If the Distance Between Ab and Cd is 3 Cm, Find the Radius of the Circle.

As per explanation provided in [here](https://www.shaalaa.com/question-bank-solutions/two-chords-ab-cd-lengths-5-cm-11-cm-respectively-circle-are-parallel-if-distance-between-ab-cd-3-cm-find-radius-circle-angle-subtended-chord-point_36386) I disagree - how can one be sure that cords are on one side of the semi-circle. I was trying the same method but judged that the chords are in each other hemisphere.

That means that the radius can vary based on distance between the chords if they are (i) on the same side of the center. (ii) on the opposite sides of the center.

In fact we get wrong answer if they are in opposite center - so how can we know from an approach when to consider chords on same / other side.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is not immediately clear that the two chords should be on the same side of the center. So you are right to *prove* that indeed it is impossible that they are on opposite sides of the center.

One way to prove this is to note that the radius $r$ of the circle satisfies $r\geq\tfrac{11}{2}$, because the circle has a chord of length $11$. Then by Pythagoras the distance from the chord of length $5$ to the center is
$$\sqrt{r^2-\left(\tfrac52\right)^2}\geq\sqrt{\frac{11^2-5^2}{2^2}}=2\sqrt{6}>3,$$
so if the distance to the other chord is $3$ then it cannot be on the other side of the center.

Comment: Your observation states true if we know certain params of circle? Hence I believe there cannot be any generic way to predict points as per question exists on same side of a circle or not?

Comment: Look at this question : Three girls Reshma, Salma and Mandip are playing a game by standing on a circle of radius 5m drawn in a park. Reshma throws a ball to Salma, Salma to Mandip, Mandip to Reshma. If the distance between Reshma and Salma and between Salma and Mandip is 6m each, what is the distance between Reshma and Mandip? If we consider them on either sides of circle it is quiet difficult to get answer - however the answer is mentioned at https://www.teachoo.com/1268/455/Ex-10.4--5---Three-girls-Reshma--Salma-and-Mandip-are/category/Ex-10.4/

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Personally, I would make two sets of calculations: one for same semi-circle and another for opposing semi-circle. In that manner, potential impossibilities can be eliminated. Also, there might be scenarios where two correct solutions are revealed. I feel that the example failed to address this, so you were right to be astute to it.
In fact, come to think of it, there will always be a solution in the same semi-circle. Then the question remains, what else can we do to determine whether there is an opposing semi-circle solution too?

Comment: What do you mean by *"there will always be a solution in the same semi-circle"*? For chords of length $11$ and $5$ at distance $5$, for example, this isn't true.

Comment: Thank you Servaes, you are correct. I made the mistake of looking at an ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. I believe the principle is correct to answer your question.
The given example used lengths, but if displacements were used instead, then positive and negative values would come into play. I will clarify what I mean.
With a circle centre O at the origin of an x-y grid, the equation is x^2 + y^2 = r^2.
If we stick to horizontal chords, we can say that half a chord length is equal to the x-coordinate of where the chord intersects the circle (considering only x > 0). We could also agree to set up the smaller chord to lie above the x-axis, namely where y>0. We will call the smaller chord, "CHORD 2".
Immediately we can set up 2 equations:
A) x1^2 + y1^2 = r^2
B) x2^2 + y2^2 = r^2
We also know that y2-y1 = 3
So our equations become:
A) x1^2 + y1^2 = r^2
B) x2^2 + (y1 + 3)^2 = r^2
Note that Equation A = Equation B = r^2
So, x1^2 + y1^2 = x2^2 + (y1 + 3)^2
Hence, for CHORD 1, (y1 + 3)^2 - y1^2 + (x2^2 - x1^2) = 0
Simplified, 6y1 = x1^2 - x2^2 - 9
Using x1 = 11/2 and x2 =5/2, we get:
6y1 = 121/4 - 25/4 - 9 = 15
So y1 = 15/6 = 5/2 > 0, so the solution is in the same semicircle.
Now it is an easy matter to substitute x1= 11/2 and y1 = 5/2 into
x^2 + y^2 = r^2
121/4 + 25/4 = r^2
So r = SQRT(36.5)

As for a generic formal to decide if the 2 chords lie in the same semicircle,
Use 6y1 = x1^2 - x2^2 - d^2
where x1 = larger chord/2 ,
x2 = shorter chord/2 ,
d = perpendicular distance between the chords.
If y1 > 0, then chords lie in same semi-circle.
If y1 < 0, then chords lie in opposite semi-semicircles.
I hope this helps.

Comment: This answer would be improved by using MathJax ([tutorial here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) to typeset the mathematical expressions. Also splitting it into smaller paragraphs would help.

Comment: But diameter is the greatest  chord?

Comment: Look at this question : Three girls Reshma, Salma and Mandip are playing a game by standing on a circle of radius 5m drawn in a park. Reshma throws a ball to Salma, Salma to Mandip, Mandip to Reshma. If the distance between Reshma and Salma and
between Salma and Mandip is 6m each, what is the distance between Reshma and Mandip? The answer is explained https://www.teachoo.com/1268/455/Ex-10.4--5---Three-girls-Reshma--Salma-and-Mandip-are/category/Ex-10.4/

Comment: But I still was getting wrong when I placed them in different sides of the circle? Your observation states true if we know certain params of circle? Hence I believe there cannot be any generic way to predict points as per question exists on same side of a circle or not?

Comment: Here's a shorter method: Lets call Reshma R, Salma S, Mandip M and add T on the opposite side to to S.Triangles RTS & TMS are both right angled. R and M are each 90 degrees (from Circle Theorem, the angle in a semicircle is always 90 degrees).Consider triangle RTS. It is a 3:4:5 triangle, so RT = 8. RT is perpendicular to TS, so the area of the triangle is simply 6 x 8 / 2 = 24. We also know that the area can be found by multiplying ST (the diameter of 10) x half RM / 2. Hence 24 = 10 x 0.5 RM / 2. Therefore distance RM = 9.6. This is clearer if you sketch a diagram too.

Comment: With regard to 'getting the answer wrong when placed in different sides of the circle': In my solution, I chose to position the SMALLER horizontal chord above the y-axis. This means it will automatically be the highest chord. The longer chord will be below this by 3 units (so the equation x1^2 + y1^2 = r^2 B) x2^2 + (y1 + 3)^2 = r^2 will still hold true), without any knowledge of whether it is above or below the x-axis, i.e. which semicircle. Then the maths [6y1 = x1^2 - x2^2 - d^2 ] determines y1 as positive or negative, which informs you of which semicircle the second chord is in.

Comment: Apologies. As I'm am new to this forum, I don't yet know how to make paragraphs and haven't learned MathsJax yet.